# Keras predicting multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I tried to predict a model with input shape of **(3040,1)**  and when I tried to predict an array of shape **(1,3040,1)** it is returning and array of shape **(1,3040,1)** when I am expecting only one number between 1 and 0. I Tried changing shape to **(3040,1)** and **(1,3040)** and its producing output of shape **(3040,1,1)** but second one is returning a ValueError

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 3040)`

This is the model

```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(units = 3040, input_shape = (3040,1), activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(units = 2027, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Please inform me if I did something wrong.

Comment: It makes no difference, that is incorrect advice.

Comment: If you have 1 feature per row, then your input shape should just be `(1,)`

Comment: `units` is the number of neurons and is not really related to the shape of the data in this case. Reduce that to something like 100 otherwise your model will take a long time to train

Comment: @ML_Engine I changed input shape to (1,) it returning ValueError  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (1, 3040)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working sample code**

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(3040,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3040, input_shape = (3040,1) , activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2027, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.output_shape
```

**Output**

```
(None, 3040, 1)
```